# How can I avoid multiple starting of a bash script?

Tags: bash, ftp, awk, instance

I wrote a little bash script called "wp", which upload files to an ftp server. It uses the wput utility. It takes the list of files from a text file. When uploading is ready it comments out the line with a double cross in the text file. The success of the upload is detected according to the last line in the logfile. My question is how can I avoid multiple starting of my script? I am trying to detect with pgrep if the instance is running, but doesn't work correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(pgrep ^wp$|wc -l)" -eq "2" ]

then 
  echo "$(pgrep ^wp$)"
  echo "$(pgrep ^wp$|wc -l)"
  echo "wp script is starting..."
else 
  echo "$(pgrep ^wp$)"
  echo "$(pgrep ^wp$|wc -l)"
  echo "wp script is already running!"
  exit
fi

server="ftp://username:password@ftp.ftpserver.com"
logfile=~/uploads.log
listfile=~/uploads.txt
list_backup=~/uploads_bak000.txt

while read f;
do
 ret=""

 if [ "${f:0:1}" = "#" -o "$f"1 = 1 ] 
 then
  if [ "$f"1 = 1 ] 
  then
   :
   #echo "invalid string: "$f
  else
   #first character is remark sign # then empty command -> :
   echo "remark line skipped: "$f 
  fi
 else
  #while string $ret is empty
  while [ -z "$ret" ]
  do
   wput "$f" --tries=-1 "$server" 2>&1|tee -a $logfile #> /dev/null
   ret=$(tail -n 1 "$logfile"|grep "FINISHED\|Nothing\|Skipped\|Transfered")
  done
  if [ -n "$ret" ]
  then
   cat $listfile > $list_backup
   awk -v f="$f" '{if ($0==f && $0!~/#/) print "#" $0; else print $0;}' $list_backup > $listfile
  fi
 fi 
done < $listfile
```

Answer (score 2):

There are quick-n-dirty solutions that use ps with grep (don't do this).

It is better to use a lock file as a "mutex". A nice way of doing this is by using a directory as a lock file (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045).

I would also suggest taking a look at:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_make_sure_only_one_copy_of_my_script_can_run_at_a_time.3F
, which mentions use of `setlock`(http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/setlock.html) that abstracts the lock file handling for you.

Comment: Thx, making an emtpy directory in /tmp solved the problem. I think it must be deleted in the end of my script, but what happens if my script is aborted with Ctrl+C and I would like to restart it? It won't start due to presence of the lock directory.

Comment: @Konstantin, you need to read the BashFAQ link, the answer is there.

Comment: @Konstantin: You need to use the trap command to make sure that rm executes after a signal is caught. But as Glenn says: do read the rest of BashFAQ. It includes other gems like a nice explanation for why you would go for mkdir over other approaches, the mention of the remaining stale lock risk that needs to be considered (in case of kill -9) and `flock` that could be used if you are on linux.